# Program crashes with strtok [C]

Tags: c, list, token, strtok

i got some problems using the function `strtok()`.
In this exercise, my teacher asked to use it in order to tokenize a single string, then save even words in a list, then print all the even tokens and their occurrences. But the program crashes after i write the input string. Can someone explain me where's the problem?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define Dim 100

struct node{
int occ;
char sbuffer[Dim];
struct node *next;
}; 

struct node *first = NULL;

void occorrenze();
void insert(char *tkn);

int main(){

char array[Dim];
char buff[Dim];
char* token;

printf("Insert string: ");
gets(array);

for(token=strtok(array, " ") ; token!=NULL ; token=strtok(NULL," ") ){

    if ((strlen(token)%2)==0){
        insert(token);
        }

}

occorrenze();

 }

 void insert(char *tkn) {
 struct node *new_node;
 new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 strcpy(new_node->sbuffer, tkn);
 new_node->occ = 1;
 new_node->next = first;
 first = new_node;
 }

 void occorrenze() {
 struct node *p;
 struct node *s;
 for(p = first; p != NULL; p = p->next){    
     for(s = p; s != NULL; s = s->next){
         if(strcmp(s->sbuffer, p->sbuffer) == 0){
         p->occ++;
         }
      }
 }
 printf("\n%s\n%d\n",p->sbuffer, p->occ);
 }
```

(Sorry for my bad english ^^)

Comment: Where in your program does it crash? If you run it in a debugger, it should tell you this vitally important piece of information for you to add to your question

Comment: It crushes in function occorrenze() before the first for

Comment: A debugger will tell you the exact line the code crashes on though, not something vague like you've just given us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your `printf()` at the end of `occorrenze()`

```
printf("\n%s\n%d\n",p->sbuffer, p->occ);
```

At this point `p` is NULL because your `for` loop has completed

```
for (p = first; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
```

The code you have for finding matches is basically correct, I would just modify it a bit (you'll only need a single loop) and move it to `insert()` so that you don't have to add the word a second time if it is already in the list, then `occorenze()` can simply traverse the list and print the words and their `occ` value :

```
void insert(char *tkn) {
    struct node *new_node;
    new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    for (struct node *n = first; n != NULL; n = n->next) {
        if (strcmp(tkn, n->sbuffer) == 0) {
            n->occ++;
            return;
        }
    }

    strcpy(new_node->sbuffer, tkn);
    new_node->occ = 1;
    new_node->next = first;
    first = new_node;
}

void occorrenze() {
    for (struct node*n = first; n != NULL; n = n->next) {
        printf("%d %s\n", n->occ, n->sbuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're totally right! 
I feel really dumb..now i have to change something else in order to print only one time each even token

Comment: What exactly is your code trying to do?  Currently, it looks like you accept strings of length 2, and then count how many times each 2 char string was repeated?

Comment: For example, if input is "even example four even odd"
Output should be 
"even 2
four 1"

Comment: Ahhh, I see now...you might want to consider checking for duplicate words in `insert()` so you only have each word in your list once, with the proper value for `occ`

Comment: That's the matter, i don't know how to check for duplicate (or more) words